# How to change a single property to a dictionary of values?

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

I've this property:

```
private static Lazy<TimeLimiter> rateLimiter = new Lazy<TimeLimiter>(() =>
    TimeLimiter.GetFromMaxCountByInterval(MaxCount, Interval));
public static TimeLimiter RateLimiter => rateLimiter.Value;
```

When I first access it, it gets initialized.

The problem is, instead of having multiple instances like `RateLimiter1` , `RateLimiter2` , etc for different clients, I want to change this so it works for multiple clients. Maybe using a `dictionary` with a string key like `client1`, `client2` etc.

But I don't know how exactly initialize each key in the dictionary in the first line above. any tips? Thanks.

(sorry for the title, couldn't think of any better description :)) )

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with the dictionary? What did you try, where are you stuck?

Comment: Try to implement a solution, and come back to us with any problem you encounter during implementation. Asking what code to write is not on-topic here. To get you started, I'd expect you need a `Dictionary<Client,TimeLimiter>`, if your clients are known (and used) classes in the code. Otherwise, you'll need to define an identifier (string, int, doesn't matter. Let's assume string), and end up with a `Dictionary<string,TimeLimiter>`. Everything else to solve this can be Googled.

Comment: @Flater  I know how to define a dictioinary. the problem is the first line of code above, how to use lazy for every item in the dictionary. I'm stuck there

Comment: @nvoigt please look at above comment

Comment: @Blendester: Generic types are stackable, e.g `Dictionary<string, Lazy<TimeLimiter>>`. In general, if you can use a type (e.g. `Lazy<TimeLimiter>` as the type of a variable, you can use it as a generic type parameter (barring any type requirements on the generic class you're using, which is out of scope for your issue). Note that the stackability is virtually unlimited: e.g. `Dictionary<string,List<Lazy<Nullable<TimeLimiter>>>>` as a random example.

Comment: If you are doing this for multiple clients I would strongly suggest you use `ConcurrentDictionary` over `Dictionary`.

Comment: @mjwills Here is the implementation of [`GetFromMaxCountByInterval`](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/RateLimiter/blob/master/RateLimiter/TimeLimiter.cs)

Comment: @mjwills yes. just around 10 values will be added to the dictionary. should I still use `ConcurrentDictionary `?

Comment: If multiple threads are involved, yes. Using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378676%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread-safe solution (generally necessary if being used by multiple clients) would look something like:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<TimeLimiter>> ratelimiters = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<TimeLimiter>>();

public static TimeLimiter GetRateLimiterForClient(string clientId)
{
    return ratelimiters.GetOrAdd(clientId, c => 
            new Lazy<TimeLimiter>(() =>
                TimeLimiter.GetFromMaxCountByInterval(MaxCount, Interval)))
                .Value;
}
```

`ConcurrentDictionary`'s `GetOrAdd` will return the existing `Lazy` if it exists, or `Add` a new one if necessary. `.Value` will then get the `TimeLimiter` from that `Lazy`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
private static Dictionary<string, Lazy<TimeLimiter>> rateLimiters = new Dictionary<string, Lazy<TimeLimiter>>();

public static TimeLimiter GetRateLimiterForClient(string clientId)
{
    if (!rateLimiters.ContainsKey(clientId))
    {
        rateLimiters.Add(clientId, 
            new Lazy<TimeLimiter>(() => 
                TimeLimiter.GetFromMaxCountByInterval(MaxCount, Interval)));
    }
    return rateLimiters[clientId].Value;
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but answers to "what code to write" questions are generally downvote magnets. Not because your answer to the question is wrong, but because it's wrong to answer such a question.

Comment: @Flater But I think it answers my question. I need to test it though

Comment: @Blendester: "The Smurfs" is a correct answer to "What does Gargamel hate the most?"; but that doesn't mean that the question (or the answer) should be posted to StackOverflow. As I said: _Not because your answer to the question is wrong, but because it's wrong to answer such a question._

Comment: @Flater Man :)) stand in front of the window and breathe some fresh air.. If I could complete the code why would I ask in the first place.

Comment: @Flater - whilst I appreciate what you're saying, it's not like the answer required a huge amount of coding.  I Personally post on here as I like to help people - When 90% of the time googling things ends up sending you to StackOverflow anyway, I don't see how a simple thing like this is a problem.    Lots of people seem obsessed with wandering around being policemen for seemingly very minor infractions - I don't understand what motivates them half the time...

Comment: (Not aiming this at you personally - happy to discuss on here of course.  In fact I applaud you for not downvoting and commenting instead.  The anonymous downvote is something that should be banned IMO)

Comment: @GPW: I get your issue with the anonymous downvote, but if someone else agrees with the existing downvote (including a reason given in comments), then they should be able to downvote without having to duplicate the comment.